# How to avoid rc.local been executed?

Tags: linux, bash, boot

I created a rc.local in /etc/ on Ubuntu 18.04

The content is

```
sleep 180
reboot
```

I thought I can stop this during the 180 seconds, but the fact is it just hang there waiting 180 seconds then reboot.

This means I can't never normal login, it will just repeat reboot.

I tried to boot by another disk and try to mount the problematic Ubuntu.

I found it can't be mount.

I tried to mount the problematic Ubuntu, `mount /dev/sdb1`, it response error. It can't be mount

Any way to recover this?

Comment: Tell us more about what you tried. It sounds like a good approach. But there is too little detail to be able to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: You have not specified where to mount it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a way to fix this.

By pressing RIGHT 'shift', (the left shift doesn't work) the grub menu will show up.

Then I can select enter emergency mode, after that, OS boot into the shell, I can edit /etc/rc.local